# Data frame transposes when Has only 1 Row

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, stringr

I have a data.frame that is generated as the result of a number of other actions and is required for further actions to proceed. A small example is presented below.

```
messy = data.frame(code = c("23740", "26501", "29458"), 
reducer = c("15ml", "80mm flanged", "80mm"), type = c("1_dash_2_dash_3",
"adaptor", "adaptor"), stringsAsFactors = F)
messy$volume = character(nrow(messy))
messy$length = character(nrow(messy))
```

In general it has a lot of rows but on occasions may only have one row.  I apply the following line of code to it to prepare it for further actions.

```
library(stringr)
messy = data.frame(apply(messy, 2, function(x) paste(" ", str_trim(x), " ",
sep = "")), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

So far, all is fine with multiple rows. However when I pass it a one row dataframe the dataframe transposes and therefore becomes unusable.

```
messy = messy[2,] 
str(messy) # 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  5 variables:
messy = data.frame(apply(messy, 2, function(x) paste(" ", str_trim(x), " ",
sep = "")), stringsAsFactors = F)
str(messy) # 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  1 variable:
```

How do I prevent this behavior? I can't see anything in the data.frame documentation. I tried wrapping messy in I() but that didn't help either. I ran the apply on rows (1) instead of columns (2) with no success either.I am very confused.

Comment: Hi @jogo & thnx. The following just added a logical column. It did not solve the problem alas. `messy = data.frame(apply(messy, 2, function(x) paste(" ", str_trim(x), " ",  sep = "")), stringsAsFactors = F, drop = F)`

Comment: The `drop=FALSE` is not in the `data.frame` call.  Also, if you are doing a columnwise operation in data.frame, use `lapply`

Comment: @akrun  raised the real point: the use of `apply` here is wrong and should replaced with `lapply`. To get the structure back, the correct line is `messy[]<-lapply(messy, ...)` (no need to call `data.frame`).

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Swapping to lapply seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Thanks also @nicola. I did need to keep the data.frame call though as lapply coerced it to a list. But I'm very happy. :)

Comment: @CallumH try `sapply()` .